# distutils IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, installation, pip, setup.py

I was trying to upload my [library](https://github.com/pyTeens/producti-gestio) to https://pypi.org when this happened:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 44, in <module>
    keywords=['producti-gestio', 'python', 'api', 'rest'],
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in 
run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in 
run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/upload.py", line 64, in 
run
    self.upload_file(command, pyversion, filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/upload.py", line 158, in 
upload_file
    value = valve[1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I don't know exactly what happened, I checked all files of my library, but all is fine! (I hope)

**setup.py**:

```
from distutils.core import setup

url = 'https://github.com/pyTeens/producti-gestio/archive/v0.3.0.tar.gz',

setup(
    name='producti_gestio',
    packages=['producti_gestio',
              'producti_gestio.core',
              'producti_gestio.decorator',
              'producti_gestio.project',
              'producti_gestio.server',
              'producti_gestio.utils'],
    version='0.3.0',
    description='A new simple web server',
    author='Gabriel Hearot',
    author_email='gabriel@hearot.it',
    url='https://github.com/pyTeens/producti-gestio',
    download_url=url,
    scripts=['bin/producti-gestio'],
    keywords=['producti-gestio', 'python', 'api', 'rest'],
)
```

Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: On a whim: what if `keywords` is a single string, instead of a list? `keywords='producti-gestio python api rest'`

Comment: @sam Nothing changes.
[...]
    value = value[1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the comma at the end, it make url tuple type.
`download_url` and `url` expects string

```
url = 'https://github.com/pyTeens/producti-gestio/archive/v0.3.0.tar.gz',
```

Example:

```
>>> url = 'http://abc',
>>> type(url)
<type 'tuple'>
```

Comment: Right! Thank you! Thank you!